# Extending $GL(n,O_A(A))_0$ to $GL(n,O_X(X))_0$, where $X$ is compact real algebraic variety of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is closed subvariety of $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let $O_X(X)$ be the set of all rational function $f=\frac{q}{p}:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $p\neq 0$ on $X$. Let $X$ be compact real algebraic variety of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ be closed subvariety of $X$. Let $GL(n,O_X(X))_0$ be the connected component of $I_n$ in $GL(n,O_X(X))$. I know from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.5048.pdf) Lemma 13 that $M(n,O_A(A))$ can be extended to $M(n,O_X(X))$ and I know from [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/complex-topological-ktheory/1C248AFD0F3AE9B0BE218F37D34D470F) proposition 1.3.16 that the restriction of elements of $M(n,C(X))$ to $M(n,C(A))$ determines a continuous surjective group homomorphism from $GL(n,C(X))_0$ to $GL(n,C(A))_0$, where $C(X)$ is the set of continuous function $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}.$

edit:

The topology on $M(n,C(X))$ and $M(n,O_X(X))$ is given by the supremum norm
$$\Vert A\Vert_{\infty}=sup\{\Vert A(x)\Vert_{op} |x\in X\}.$$

The topology on $X$ is inherent from $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that $f=\frac{q}{p}:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
The topology on $GL(n,O_A(A))_0$ is subspace topology from $M(n,O_X(X))$.

It is clear that $GL(n,O_X(X))_0$ can restrict into $GL(n,O_A(A))_0$. So I want to know whether $GL(n,O_A(A))_0$ can extend to $GL(n,O_X(X))_0$ or not. Or equivalently, whether $GL(n,O_X(X))_0$ can restrict onto $GL(n,O_A(A))_0$ or not.

Comment: Why $GL(n,O_X(X))_0=\{M\in M(n,O_X(X)),\forall x\in X,\forall v\neq 0\in\mathbb{R}^n, v^{t}M(x)v>0\}$? $\gamma (t)$ may not be invertible , so it may not lies in $GL(n,O_X(X))$.

Comment: Why $\gamma(t)$ satisfies the condition? $M$ is a matrix with $f=\frac{q}{p}$ in each entry, I can't not see $\gamma(t)$ lies in $GL(n,O_X(X))$.

Comment: Which step is unclear to you.

Comment: First, why $GL(n,O_X(X))_0=\{ M\in M(n,O_X(X)),\forall x\in X, \forall v\neq 0\in\mathbb{R}^n,v^{t}M(x)v>0\}$ ? Second, it is not clear for me that $\gamma(t)$ is invertible because $det(A+B)\neq det(A)+det(B)$. I don't know how to conclude that $\gamma(t)$ is invertible. Finally, why this doesn't give a lift from $GL(n,O_A(A))_0$ to $GL(n,O_X(X))_0$. Thank you for your comment, and I am sorry that I am going to sleep now. I will reply you tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry I spotted my mistake. Obviously $v^\top N(x) v$ can change of sign when $N$ moves along a curve $I\to M$ in $GL(n)$

Comment: It seems that set is the set of positive definite matrix. Thank you for your comment again.